# Why my celery tasks not working with MQTT client?

Tags: celery, paho, celerybeat

I want set up some Celery periodic tasks to do something with Paho MQTT client. The worker showed that it was executed successfully. But on my Cloud MQTT Broker Message Feed , there was nothing.

```
### mqtt.py
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

#The callback for connecting to CloudMQTT broker
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connecting to CloudMQTT broker: "+ mqtt.connack_string(rc))

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print("Received message '" + str(message.payload) + "' on topic '"
        + message.topic  + "' with QoS " + str(message.qos))

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.username_pw_set('bmlflxes', 'Mj8LHanZvdkf')
client.connect('m11.cloudmqtt.com', 12180),

### tasks.py
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from mqtt import client 

app = Celery('tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='pyamqp://')
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
# Executes at sunset in Melbourne
'test': {
    'task': 'tasks.hello',
    'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
    'args': (),
        },
 }
@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@app.task
def hello():
    client.publish('sys', 'hello')


### Worker log
[2018-09-13 21:44:00,048: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task test (tasks.hello)
[2018-09-13 21:44:00,053: DEBUG/MainProcess] tasks.hello sent. id->7d88ae4b-821c-4485-87bc-454ac9bbac5e
[2018-09-13 21:44:00,054: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 59.94 seconds.
```